# Reference FragmentActivity to external Interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, externalinterface

I want to call a function in a fragment from a class. How do i attach FragmentActivity to External Interface like i attach Activities

Currently for Activity, the class contains

```
public interface externalInterface {
    public void gotoNext();
}

public void setActivity(externalInterface activity) {
    parentActivity = activity;
}
```

and i called

```
parentActivity.gotoNext();
```

Activity has

```
@Override
public void gotoNext() {
    //Do something
}
```

Similarly i need to call gotoNext() function in a fragment from the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function you want to call is already in the Activity then you can do something like the code below and it will work -

The key is, in the Fragment you have a method called `getActivity()` which you can use to access methods in your activity.

```
public interface ExternalInterface {
  public void gotoNext();
}

public MyActivity implments ExternalInterface {
 public void gotoNext(){
 //Do something here
 }
}
```

In your Fragment, you can call

```
 public MyFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onCreateView(....){
 ((ExternalInterface )getActivity()).gotoNext();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you want to use the  **gotoNext()** in the fragments which be will there in FragmentActivty

1. make sure fragment activity implements interface.
2. In fragment call `getActivity()` can downcast to your interface and you call the method (make sure `onActivityCreated()` call completed)